# Error al ejecutar aplicación Yii2 - Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved

Tags: php, yii2

Estoy presentando el siguiente problema y es que al momento de abrir mi aplicacion de Yii2, me sale siguiente error **Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La version de Yii2 es 2.0.15, y de PHP 7.2.3

Comment: Que versión de php estás usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando la version PHP 7.2.3

Comment: Hay errores con php 7.2 y yii2 por lo mismo, bájate como máximo a 7.1.*

Comment: Antes tenia un error parecido a este y me decian que realizara un composer update

Comment: como se llama tu clase que creaste?

Comment: Ahí viene una liga de la documentación
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.13/framework/UPGRADE.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dice que la clase Object ya no existe y que uses BaseObject en su lugar.

Yo en su momento bajé de nuevo a la versión 7.1 por haber leído que había problemas con ciertas cosas en yii2 framework debido a ciertos cambios de php (ahora object es una palabra reservada del lenguaje → https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-object)

Deberás corregir manualmente todas las clases que heredan de `yii\base\Object` y ahora deberán heredar de `yii\base\BaseObject`.

Para este proceso lo ideal es que sigas las notas de actualización oficial:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.13/framework/UPGRADE.md#upgrade-from-yii-2012

Answer (score 0):

Ya que en la versión de php 7.2.3 Object es una palabra reservada, necesitas renombrar el archivo y las clases que extienden de ese archivo.

- `mv vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php`. para renombrar el archivo.
- `find ./vendor/yiisoft/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/class Object/class BaseObject/g' {} +`. para renombrar la clase.
- `find ./vendor/yiisoft/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/extends Object/extends BaseObject/g' {} +`. para renombrarlo en las clases que extienden de el.
- `find ./vendor/yiisoft/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/yii\\base\\Object/yii\\base\\BaseObject/g' {} +`. modificar las rutas asociadas a la clase.
- `find ./vendor/yiisoft/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\/base\/Object.php/\/base\/BaseObject.php/g' {} +i`. edita la ruta al archivo en el archivo de classes.php